# how to display view when orientation is changed is swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to display one view when it is in portrait mode, and another view in landscape mode. Is it possible? I tried this code but view is overlapping. How to fix it?

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    if (app.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape) 

        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1300
            , height: 50))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        //        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Header")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: "Landscape")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
       display1()

    if (app.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait)

        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800
            , height: 50))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        //        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Header")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: "background")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        print(String.self, "sandeep potrait")
       displayKeyboard()
```

Comment: @nhgrif no its not the copy of that link mate, this is what the problem i am facing like i created 6 button 3X2 (row x column ) in portrait mode and it has to change into 2x3 in landscape mode, but what happening is after entering in to landscape mode, view controller over writing the view, which means after landscape orientation i can see both 3x2 and 2x3 view in one view its tricky thing

Comment: The linked question is a simplified version of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide or remove the view that you don't want to see in current orientation.

To do that you need to create properties for these views and something like:

```
var portraitImageView: UIImageView?
var landscapeImageView: UIImageView?

func ... {
    if (app.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape) {
        var imageView: UIImageView
        ...
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        self.landscapeImageView = imageView

        self.portraitImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.portraitImageView = nil
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anoton Tyutin nope its not working any other option pls

Comment: @Sandpie What issue are your facing ? do you switch the variable correctly in the `else` case ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo i am facing like i created 6 button 3X2 (row x column ) in portrait mode and it has to change into 2x3 in landscape mode, but what happening is after entering in to landscape mode, view controller over writing the view, which means after landscape orientation i can see both 3x2 and 2x3 view in one view its tricky thing